# Remove tag containing a certain text

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this HTML code:

```
<p>
    <strong>
        Read our full
        <a href="">
            review
        </a>
    </strong>
</p>
```

I would like to remove all 'p' tags containing 'Read our full' string using BeautifulSoup. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work

```
for x in soup.find_all("p", text=re.compile('Read our full')): 
    x.decompose()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use pseudo class `:-soup-contains("Read our full")`

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<p>
    <strong>
        Read our full
        <a href="">
            review
        </a>
    </strong>
</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for e in soup.select('p:-soup-contains("Read our full")'):
    e.decompose()

soup
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(It's generally a good idea to reverse the results if you're going to be removing them one by one, so that if there are nested tags that qualify, the inner tag gets removed first and none of the results are removed before the loop reaches them.)</sub>

Using `string` argument instead of `text` used to work for a while, but it seems not any more; however, you can use a function or a `lambda` expression:

```py
for p in reversed(soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name=='p' and 'Read our full' in t.text)): 
    if 'Read our full' in p.text:
        p.decompose()
```

the additional `if` also keeps outer `p` from getting deleted after inner `p` has been deleted, like `<div><p><p>Read our full article</p> here</p></div>` would become `<div><p>here</p></div>` instead of just `<div></div>`.

Comment: Both of your suggestions didn't work.

Comment: @СергейКох thanks for pointing it out. using `string` instead of `text` is supposed to work according to the docs [and did work for a while] but it's no longer working the same...I've updated my answer but I'll freely admit that the other answer offers a much better solution